# ListBox DragDrop auto Scroll issue?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have successfully implemented drag drop within a ListBox using:

Bea Stollnitz - How can I drag and drop items between data bound ItemsControls:
http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488#.U15ozvldU9Y

However, when the list has a scrollbar and I am at the end of the list, the ListBox does not scroll automatically while I'm dragging an item.
How do I incorporate that behavior?

EDIT: When I am over the bottom border of the list I want it to scroll so I can drop somewhere on a lower item?

Comment: You mean when you are over the bottom border of the list you want it to scroll so you can drop somwhere on a lower item?

Comment: do you mean you want to scroll down after a item is dropped?

Comment: Yes @Didier...Thats the behavior i Want

Answer (score 2):

I achieve this using an attached property which adds the capability to scroll the control as the mouse moves towards the top or bottom of it while dragging. Here is the attached property class:-

```
public class DragDropAttProps
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollOnDragDropProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ScrollOnDragDrop",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(DragDropAttProps),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, HandleScrollOnDragDropChanged));

    public static bool GetScrollOnDragDrop(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(ScrollOnDragDropProperty);
    }
    public static void SetScrollOnDragDrop(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ScrollOnDragDropProperty, value);
    }

    private static void HandleScrollOnDragDropChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var container = d as FrameworkElement;
        if (d == null)
        {
            Debug.Fail("Invalid type!");
        }

        Unsubscribe(container);

        if (true.Equals(e.NewValue))
        {
            Subscribe(container);
        }
    }

    private static void Subscribe(FrameworkElement container)
    {
        container.PreviewDragOver += OnContainerPreviewDragOver;
    }

    private static void Unsubscribe(FrameworkElement container)
    {
        container.PreviewDragOver -= OnContainerPreviewDragOver;
    }

    private static void OnContainerPreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        const double Tolerance = 60;
        const double Offset = 20;

        var container = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (container == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var scrollViewer = GetFirstVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(container); 
        if (scrollViewer == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var verticalPos = e.GetPosition(container).Y;

        if (verticalPos < Tolerance)
        {
            // Top of visible list? Scroll up.
            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - Offset);
        }
        else if (verticalPos > container.ActualHeight - Tolerance) 
        {
            // Bottom of visible list? Scroll down.
            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset + Offset);
        }
    }

    private static T GetFirstVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child is T)
                {
                    return (T)child;
                }

                var childItem = GetFirstVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (childItem != null)
                {
                    return childItem;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Finally, specify the attached property on the control's XAML. Disclaimer: I use this approach on a TreeView but it *should* work on any scrollable control such as a list box:-

```
<UserControl xmlns:attProps="clr-namespace:MyAssembly.AttachedProperties;assembly=MyAssembly">

    <TreeView attProps:DragDropAttProps.ScrollOnDragDrop="True">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple and complete drag drop example using a ListBox, and making auto-scrolling. I think the answer from Andrew Stephens is alreading answering your question due it manage the autoscroll, and also it use `attached properties`, that it is a good practice.

This is an example for a complete drag & drop inside an example windows, from and to the same list box.

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private const int dragMargin = 10;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void ListBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed || list.SelectedItem == null)
            return;
        if (e.MouseDevice.DirectlyOver != null)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(list, list.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.All);
        }
    }

    private void list_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var source = sender as ListBox;
        if (source == null)
            return;
        var item = e.Data.GetData(typeof (ContentControl));
        if (item == null)
            return;
        source.Items.Remove(item);
        var listAsTarget = sender as ListBox;
        if (listAsTarget == null)
            return;

        var mouseDirectitem = e.OriginalSource;
        var listItem = VisualFindParentFromType<ListBoxItem>(mouseDirectitem as UIElement);

        if (listItem == null)
        {
            listAsTarget.Items.Insert(0, item);
            return;
        }

        var insertBefore = true;
        var pointReletiveItem = e.GetPosition(listItem);
        Debug.WriteLine("Item Height: {0}", listItem.ActualHeight);
        Debug.WriteLine("Y: {0}", pointReletiveItem.Y);
        if (pointReletiveItem.Y > listItem.ActualHeight / 2)
            insertBefore = false;

        var index = listAsTarget.Items.IndexOf(listItem.Content);
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            listAsTarget.Items.Insert(insertBefore ? index : index + 1, item);
            return;
        }

        listAsTarget.Items.Add(item);
    }

    private T VisualFindParentFromType<T>(DependencyObject element) where T : UIElement
    {
        if (element == null)
            return default(T);
        if (element is T)
            return (T)element;
        return VisualFindParentFromType<T>(VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element));
    }

    private T FindChildrenFromType<T>(DependencyObject element) where T : UIElement
    {
        if (element == null)
            return default(T);
        if (element is T)
            return (T) element;
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
        {
            var result = FindChildrenFromType<T>(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i));
            if (!Equals(default(T), result))
                return result;
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    private void list_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var source = e.Source as ListBox;

        if (source == null)
            return;
        var point = e.GetPosition(source);

        var scrollViewer = FindChildrenFromType<ScrollViewer>(source);
        if (scrollViewer == null)
            return;

        if (point.Y < dragMargin)
        {
            scrollViewer.LineUp();
        }
        else if (point.Y > Math.Abs(source.ActualHeight - dragMargin))
        {
            scrollViewer.LineDown();
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="list" Height="90" AllowDrop="True" MouseMove="ListBox_MouseMove" Drop="list_Drop" PreviewDragOver="list_DragOver">
        <ContentControl>
            Item 1
        </ContentControl>
        <ContentControl>
            Item 2
        </ContentControl>
        <ContentControl>
            Item 3
        </ContentControl>
        <ContentControl>
            Item 4
        </ContentControl>
        <ContentControl>
            Item 5
        </ContentControl>
        <ContentControl>
            Item 6
        </ContentControl>
        <ContentControl>
            Item 7
        </ContentControl>
        <ContentControl>
            Item 8
        </ContentControl>
        <ContentControl>
            Item 9
        </ContentControl>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Hope this helps...